# android 4.4 adb screenrecorder help needed

Tags: android, adb, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to record the screen on my nexus 7. As the tutorial suggested I did all the changes required and I am now able to login to the adb shell. From adb shell I am running the command `screenrecord --verbose /storage/emulated/0/b.mp4` . All the examples which I found by googling uses `/sdcard/b.mp4` as the location. since my tab does not have any sd card, I am trying to save it to the phone memory. But I am getting *** No such file or directory*** error.

Comment: Sounds like your first step needs to be to figure out if this location actually exists and is writable.

Comment: Try `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/b.mp4`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, when I used set command I found `EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/emulated/legacy` parameter set and then I redirected it to /storage/emulated/legacy/b.mp4. Thanks.